# How to change the value of a user within an array list whilst using an if statement?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am stuck on one final part of my assignment, I have created two array lists. One is an array list that lists all users within the user group and the other lists only the administrators within that user group. I have been asked to change the value of the last administrator within the second array list and set their userType to a user instead of an administrator. I've tried using an if statement to do this but I'm not too sure on how I would structure it. I will post what I have tried up to date:

**Mian class**

```
package test;

public class Main{
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserGroup2 userGroupObject2 = new UserGroup2();

        //Once method is complete, should be called here.
        }

         }
         }
```

**UserGroup2 class**

```
    package main;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;



    public class UserGroup2 {

    private ArrayList<User> administrators = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserGroup2() {
      addUser(new User("hpf1g17", "Admin", "Harry"));
      addUser(new User("bdh1285", "Admin", "Bob"));
    }

    public void addUser(User inUser) {
      this.administrators.add(inUser);
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUserIterator() {
        return administrators;
    }

//This is what I have tried so far but isn't workng
    public void setUserType()  {
        Iterator<User> it = administrators.iterator();    
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            User xxx = it.next();

            if (xxx.getUsername().equals("bdh1285")) {

               xxx.UserType = "Student";
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

**User class**

```
package main;

public class User {

  private String username;
  private String userType;
  private String name;

  User(String username, String userType, String name) {
    this.username = username;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }


  public String setUserType(String admin) {
    return userType = admin;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return username + " " + userType;
  }    
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `xxx.setUserType("Student");` perhaps?

Comment: Does the `User` instance `setUserType("Student")` was invoked on _still_ appear in `List administrators`? Congruently so?

Comment: Yeah it does, but this was meant to happen in this instance as the assignment wanted us to point out the issues that occur when you change the values of users within the two usergroups and then provide a solution.